# How can I send a text information to a servlet that creates a text file containing it?

Tags: sendto

**I created an AJAX app that should send a text info to my tomcat server, and there I should have a servlet that in theory should get that text and save it in a file**.

I created an app that gets the content of a text area and transforms it into JSON and send it to my tomcat server, there I should have a servlet that receives it and save the JSON as a text file, but I'm not sure on how to actually install/deploy my servlet in my server, plus and I don't even know how to make it communicate with the AJAX. Can you conduct me and help me through it?

Thanks in advance.

**My "Servlet"**

```
package servletPackage;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Servlet {

static String position = "THAT JSON INFO SHOULD BE HERE";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Positions.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(position);
        writer.close();
     }

}
```

**My App** "*It's actually something more complicated than this, but for an easier comprehension of my idea I created this example. That's why I'm talking about JSON, even though in this example transforming the text into JSON doesn't make any sense*"

```js
$(function() {
  alert("file has been succesfully sent");
  var data = new FormData();
  var cssData = $("#custom-css-text").val();
  data.append("custom_css", cssData);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'myserver',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert("file has been succesfully sent");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <textarea id="custom-css-text">testing</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know how to connect the ajax app with the java servlet :(

Comment: by the way your `Servlet` class isn't even a `Servlet` use IDE to generate `Servlet` for you it will create you a template. Needs to extend `extends HttpServlet`.

Comment: I'm using eclipse portable Juno 4.2, How do I do it on it?

Comment: your `Servlet` will have a `doGet` and `doPost` method to handle `get` and `post` requests. You can retrieve your data from your `textarea` by using the `request` object.  You will need to give your `textarea` a `name` can be same as `id`.  There is a lot of work to be done here hard to help with something this complex in an environment like this...I would recommend doing a lot of googling.  Also you will need to configure your `web.xml` file. Hope that's enough info to get you started.

Comment: right click on project  then `->new->Servlet` make sure you have created a `dynamic web project` not a regular `java project`.  There should be lots of tutorials out there.  `Google`

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded plugins to do it on google developers. Thank you for being so helpful

Comment: your welcome hope you figure it out!